# Laravel Application (a page) is not loading

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, server

My Laravel Application(postgreSQL used as a database) works on both local and remote servers. This application has a page that is not loading on the remote server. But load on my local computer.

After increasing the maximum execution time from 30 to 1800 or 0, don't work anymore.

Sometimes show the following error -

1. An internal server error occurred. Please try again later.
2. Gateway Timeout - The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.

Is it possible to load the page?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Check the logs in `/var/logs/nginx` if you are using `nginx` on remote server or likewise. Without code, that's the best we can suggest.

Comment: If you don't have access to the server logs you can also look in the laravel logs to see if there is a stacktrace of the error.  This usually points you in the right direction on a 500 error.

Comment: The application doesn't create any logs for that page. @JustJeremy